# Update order weight via ShipStation API

Tags: api

I'm building a ShipStation API integration that updates order weight. It works alright for orders that belong to native ShipStation store (called "Manual Orders" in my case).

However, weight update fails for orders that belong to Etsy store (these orders are created in Etsy and imported by ShipStation). I've tried both with additionalOptions and without (it's marked as optional anyway). Here's my request:

```js
{
weight:{
  value:'39',
  units:'ounces'
},
orderKey:'1009247505',
orderNumber:'1009247505',
orderDate:'2015-04-02T18:00:50.0000000',
orderStatus:'awaiting_shipment',
billTo:{
  name:'Sophia Sun',
  company:null,
  street1:null,
  street2:null,
  street3:null,
  city:null,
  state:null,
  postalCode:null,
  country:null,
  phone:null,
  residential:null,
  addressVerified:null
},
shipTo:{
  name:'Sophia Sun',
  company:null,
  street1:'9851 NE 16TH ST',
  street2:'',
  street3:null,
  city:'BELLEVUE',
  state:'WA',
  postalCode:'98004-3426',
  country:'US',
  phone:null,
  residential:true,
  addressVerified:'Address validated successfully'
},
advancedOptions:{
  warehouseId:19400,
  nonMachinable:false,
  saturdayDelivery:false,
  containsAlcohol:false,
  mergedOrSplit:false,
  parentId:null,
  storeId:29420,
  customField1:null,
  customField2:null,
  customField3:null,
  source:null,
  billToParty:null,
  billToAccount:null,
  billToPostalCode:null,
  billToCountryCode:null
},
items:[
  {
    orderItemId:180328770,
    lineItemKey:'1018978111',
    sku:'173914528',
    name:'12 Sizes Available: Indigo Decorative Throw Zipper Pillow Cover 16x16 18x18 20x20 22x22 inches',
    imageUrl:'https://img1.etsystatic.com/036/0/7621433/il_fullxfull.544582063_aw56.jpg',
    weight:null,
    quantity:1,
    unitPrice:22,
    warehouseLocation:null,
    options:[
      {
        name:'Size',
        value:'20x20 inches'
      },
      {
        name:'Fabric',
        value:'Susanna'
      }
    ],
    productId:15935328,
    fulfillmentSku:null
  },
  {
    orderItemId:180328769,
    lineItemKey:'1018978113',
    sku:'174027396',
    name:'One Taupe, Blue, Indigo, Grey Decorative Throw Pillow Cover 8 Fabrics and 7 Sizes Grey Blue Tan Accent Pillow Cover',
    imageUrl:'https://img0.etsystatic.com/041/0/7621433/il_fullxfull.544517672_fdto.jpg',
    weight:null,
    quantity:1,
    unitPrice:22,
    warehouseLocation:null,
    options:[
      {
        name:'Size',
        value:'20x20 inches'
      },
      {
        name:'Fabric',
        value:'Honeycomb'
      }
    ],
    productId:16124487,
    fulfillmentSku:null
  },
  {
    orderItemId:180328768,
    lineItemKey:'1019027922',
    sku:'173914528',
    name:'12 Sizes Available: Indigo Decorative Throw Zipper Pillow Cover 16x16 18x18 20x20 22x22 inches',
    imageUrl:'https://img1.etsystatic.com/036/0/7621433/il_fullxfull.544582063_aw56.jpg',
    weight:null,
    quantity:1,
    unitPrice:22,
    warehouseLocation:null,
    options:[
      {
        name:'Size',
        value:'20x20 inches'
      },
      {
        name:'Fabric',
        value:'Grey Cat\'s Eye'
      }
    ],
    productId:15935328,
    fulfillmentSku:null
  },
  {
    orderItemId:180328767,
    lineItemKey:'1019027924',
    sku:'173914528',
    name:'12 Sizes Available: Indigo Decorative Throw Zipper Pillow Cover 16x16 18x18 20x20 22x22 inches',
    imageUrl:'https://img1.etsystatic.com/036/0/7621433/il_fullxfull.544582063_aw56.jpg',
    weight:null,
    quantity:1,
    unitPrice:22,
    warehouseLocation:null,
    options:[
      {
        name:'Size',
        value:'20x20 inches'
      },
      {
        name:'Fabric',
        value:'Madison'
      }
    ],
    productId:15935328,
    fulfillmentSku:null
  }
]
}
```

And here's a stack trace in response:

```js
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__21`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
}
```

So, what's the right way to update the weight via ShipStation API?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? I will encounter the same issue shortly, and am interested to know how it panned out.

Comment: Same here, did you by any chance find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it through python, passing dictionary as data and got the same error. The solution for me was to pass a json encoded string with appropriate content type while POSTing to shipstation.
Code:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x = requests.post('https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/createorder', data=json.dumps(order_data),
                          auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'),
                          headers=headers)
```